# What does consume an API mean?

Tags: rest, api, soap

I am fairly new to APIs and I keep seeing this phrase "consume an API", and have looked it up however I am unable to understand it clearly.

To my understanding "consume an API" means I have an application, I am trying to retrive data from another external application. The API would be transforming the data for my application. Im just confused because it's saying consume an API, but wouldn't the API be consuming the data?

Please forgive me if I'm not making sense, this subject is very new to me and I am just trying to get a basic understanding. Please give me the longest answer you can. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the defination of API https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

> The API would be transforming the data for my application

Api won't be transforming the data for your application, rather your application would be transforming the data that an API sends, so your application is acting as a client and consuming the data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response, this is by far the best way I've seen this described.